# Javascript function is not being called

Tags: javascript, html

When I attach my javascript file to my html, and do a simple printing to the html upon a button press, it does nothing.

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="json_stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="json_creation_functions.js"></script>
        <title>UI for Curl method</title>
    </header>
    <body>      
        <form id="json_input">              
            <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="post()" > Submit</button> 
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function post() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello" ;
}
```

Comment: is your js file in the same directory as your html file?

Comment: yes they are both in the same directory

Comment: does the console say anything

Comment: Is your js file actually called "json_creation_functions.js"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<header>` tag should be `<head>` (remove `er`)

Answer (score 1):

Change `header` to `head` tag.

```js
function post() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello" ;
}
```

```html
     
            <form id="json_input">              
                <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="post()" > Submit </button> 
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
```